# Random deletion of edges in graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to delete edges in a random process in a graph as a function of p where p is from 0 to 1. In the first iteration 0.1 or 10% of the nodes are deleted randomly from the graph. In the second iteration 20% of the remaining edges are deleted and so on.
My error is occurring when the edges which have been deleted come up in the random function again.

My attempt:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import numpy as np
graph = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(20,0.3)



p_values = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]


for i in p_values:
    print(i)

for i in p_values:

    array=[]    

    n=nx.number_of_edges(graph)
    edges = list(graph.edges)

    no_edges_del = int(n*i)
    print(no_edges_del)

    for j in range(no_edges_del):
        chosen_edge = random.choice(edges)
        print(chosen_edge)
        print(chosen_edge[0])
        graph.remove_edge(chosen_edge[0], chosen_edge[1])

        GC = nx.number_of_nodes(max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph), key=len))

        array.append(GC/n)
```

error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 26, in <module>
    graph.remove_edge(chosen_edge[0], chosen_edge[1])
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 1011, in remove_edge
    raise NetworkXError("The edge %s-%s is not in the graph" % (u, v))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The edge 14-15 is not in the graph
```

Comment: Either check if the edge is in the graph before removing it or randomly choose from edges that are in the graph **at the time of choosing**.

Answer (score 0):

You get the set of edges before the for loop starts. You need to remove the edges from this set as they are removed from the graph so that they aren't chosen again during a later iteration.

Alternatively, get the set of edges from the graph on each iteration just before you choose the one to remove.

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be the following.
At each iteration you consider the current percentage `p` and remove `p*number_of_remaining_edges` edges.

```
import random
import networkx as nx

g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(20,0.3)
p_values = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]

for p in p_values:
    g.remove_edges_from(random.sample(g.edges(),k=int(p*g.number_of_edges())))
```